# ng-multi-select-dropdown not show static data passed from component

Tags: angular

`selectedItems` not show in template, I added some data into it and put inside `onInit()`, I used `[(ngModel)]` at html but it not working, I want when init component items at dropdown will selected follow `selectedItems`

component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dropdownList = [];
  selectedItems = [];
  dropdownSettings = {};
  constructor(){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedItems = [
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' }
    ];
    this.dropdownList = [
      { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Mumbai' },
      { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Bangaluru' },
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' },
      { item_id: 5, item_text: 'New Delhi' }
    ];
    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'item_id',
      textField: 'item_text',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      closeDropDownOnSelection:true,
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true
    };
  }
```

HTML

```
<div *ngIf='selectedItems!= undefined'>
  <ng-multiselect-dropdown
  [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings"
  [data]="dropdownList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

not working
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Import Forms Module in app.module.ts.It should work.

```
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Thanks you it worked, I forgot import `FormsModule`

Answer (score -1):

You set `this.selectedItems` before `this.dropdownList` in `ngOnInit()`. Swap them and it should work.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dropdownList = [
      { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Mumbai' },
      { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Bangaluru' },
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' },
      { item_id: 5, item_text: 'New Delhi' }
    ];
    this.selectedItems = [
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' }
    ];
    this.dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'item_id',
      textField: 'item_text',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      closeDropDownOnSelection:true,
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true
    };
}
```

Comment: I added ```:IDropdownSetting``` to the code snippet above. Also make sure to add: ```import { IDropdownSettings } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'; ```